# Axios Network Error after a long pending for response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, amazon-s3, axios

I m uploading a large file > 1GB to AWS S3 using nodejs , I can easily upload small files probably under 150MB , but for lareg files I can't when my website is online.
btw it's working on local host because the computer is the server.
it's failling only when website is live and after waiting for long time to send the file buffer.

this is my axios method I m using to send the file.

```
axios({
      url: BASE_URL + "add/course",
      withCredentials: true,
      method: "POST",
      timeout: 12000000,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
      data: formData,
      onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
        let progress = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
         setProgress(progress);
  }
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 202) {
          setIsLoading(false);
          setIsUploaded(true);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

I m sure it's something with axios or timeout, by the way the backend function is working fine as am sure .

in my route request I added

`req.setTimeout(1200000000);`

the error I m getting on the screenshot bellow
[image]

I m using Nginx with NodeJs , I upgraded Ngnix body max size as well.
please help , thank you.

Example:
for example when I m trying to upload a file with ! 1GB the front end sends only 150MB and then it's blocked and the server stay waiting and the axios throws the connection error .
[image]

Comment: Is there anything sitting between the web browser and the NodeJS server, such as a load balancer, or a CDN like CloudFront or Cloudflare?

Comment: For files of that size you should / need to use multi part uploads.

Comment: yes I m using CloudFlare

Comment: yes I am using multipart upload for s3 and it's working as expected on my local host , do you know how cloudFlare can effect on this and how can I fix it?

Comment: I found that cloudFlare was pointing to proxies and the timeout was auto I changed it to 5h and I desctivate the proxies , I think it should work now I m still testing a large file

Comment: now my app is Killed on the server with 502 after uploading complete , the previews setting saved my uploading from client side , but server can't handle it, I m using pm2 to manage my apps, I think the new issue related to my server's memory I will increase the memory and then I will check